# Cant connect to docker container port of some images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying investigate my issue with docker container. I lost a day when I thought that issue is in nodejs code (it has server and I am trying to connect to this server).

After investigations I found interesting thing for me.

For example - Lets run some test docker image:

```
docker run -p 888:888 -it ubuntu:16 /bin/bash
```

After that, prepare and install "simple server to listen our port":

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y netcat
nc -l 888
```

After that I going to try to `telnet localhost 888` from my system and got `telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused`. The same with `nodejs` image.

But if you try to use, for example, `nginx` container -

```
docker run -p 888:888 -it nginx /bin/bash
```

I will be successfull:

```
$telnet 127.0.0.1 888 
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

How it is possible, what I am missing? Why I can bind and use any port in `nginx` but not for other images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `nc -l 888`, you are creating a port that is listening *explicitly* for IPv4 connections. If we run `ss -tln`, we will see:

```
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q     Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN  0       1                0.0.0.0:888           0.0.0.0:*
```

When you run `telnet localhost 888` on your host, there's a good chance it's trying to connect to the IPv6 localhost address, `::1`. This connection fails if you're trying to connect an IPv4-only socket.

If you explicitly use the IPv4 loopback address by typing `telnet 127.0.0.1 888`, it should work as expected.

---

If you enable IPv6 support in `nc` by adding the `-6` parameter:

```
nc -6 -l 8888
```

Then you get a socket that listen for both IPv4 and IPv6 connections:

```
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q     Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN  0       1                      *:888                 *:*
```

And if you attempt to connect to this socket using `telnet localhost 888`, it will work as expected (as will `telnet 127.0.0.1 888`).

Most programs (like `nginx`) open multi-protocol sockets by default, so this isn't normally an issue.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! By the way - I am started these tests because I cant connect to custom nodejs application container which is binding to 8800 port. Can it be related?

Comment: is it possible "to get behaviour" like a nginx container?

Comment: Re: "is it possible "to get behaviour" like a nginx container?", I think that's exactly what I described, at least when using the `nc` tool. If you're having issues with a specific nodejs application, the easiest path forward is probably to open a new question, and include [mcve] that demonstrates the problem so that we can take a look.